# If I build a 14.04 server with OpenZFS now will I be able to move to 16.04 later?

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, zfs

I'm planning on building a new home NAS soon. Like my previous one I plan on using ZFS for the large storage pool. I know 16.04 comes out in a few weeks but I might be building sooner rather than later and was wondering if I could expect issues when upgrading to 16.04, specifically with ZFS?

My concern is with ZFS getting baked in to Ubuntu where will that leave older setups.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I moved two zfs machines already. It worked without any issues. Just removal of zfs ppa and `apt install zfsutils-linux` on 16.04 was enough.

Comment: The linux implementation still has some minor quirks which the FreeBSD or Solaris version has not, in my experience. If you are used to them, please disregard. Otherwise, FreeNAS may be an option for a NAS for you.